# Enabled Create Quotes Without a Related Opportunity but don't have permissions

Tags: quote, sharing-rule

I enabled 'Create Quotes Without a Related Opportunity' within our org. I then went to follow this [Salesforce Help Article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cpq_quotes_without_opportunities.htm&type=5) and create a sharing rule for Quote. However, I am still getting the message that I cannot create a sharing rule for this item.

Comment: I have not personally enabled this feature but changes to OWD to "Private" requires sharing recalculation on all existing records, so maybe Salesforce was still recalculating the OWD change when you tried to create a new sharing rule? Have you tried again after giving Salesforce some time to make the change and still received the error? If so, can you update your question with the actual error message?